# My blender 2.77 wont start

Tags: windows, installation

on startup my blender version 2.77 crashes, have any off you been through this and know a solution? I have already tried re-installing it but its no use.
Thanks

Comment: do you have correct version for your os ?

Comment: you mean like 32 bit or 64? yes i have the right version

Comment: did you try to compile blender from the source ?

Comment: yes i did, it didnt work

Comment: i can't understand .... you have this problem with normal install file of blender, or compiling source code ?

Comment: Source, I'll email some blender people and see if they. Can do anything.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information to be able to help you. Don't bother blender people until you have something conclusive to bother them about. What are your system specs, what operating system? This may be caused by bad graphics card or bad drivers. What GPU so you have?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have another version of Python installed on your system?

My version of Blender 2.75 would not start in Win10, complaining about unhandled exception 0xc0000409.

I re-uninstalled Blender 2.75, re-installed the MS Visual Studio redistributable (msvcr120.dll), went through the usual windows service troubleshooting steps starting from a clean boot.  All no help.  I finally ran the Program Compatibility troubleshooter on blender.exe, the diagnostics log in %appdata%/temp said "python incompatible".

So I deleted the PYTHONPATH environment variable.  Voila! Now Blender starts fine.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting everything in %appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender before installing

open explorer, copy/paste this : "%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender" in the adress bar
[image: path]
Delete everything you'll find in this folder
[image]

Comment: No, it did not work